# How to determine if type needs to be boxed?

Tags: .net, reflection, boxing, value-type

MSDN docs say that only value types need boxing, but this does not apply to string, which is a value type and does not need to be boxed. I initially tried Type.IsValueType, but since that returns true for string, I can't use it to determine whether a type really needs to be boxed. Are there any other methods you are aware of? Is string the only exception?

**UPDATE: I made a mistake in my code where I referenced an int and I thought it was a string. String is in fact a value type, thanks for pointing it out guys!**

Comment: What makes you think that string doesn't have to be boxed to String?

Comment: In my world, `typeof(string).IsValueType` return `false`. A string is a class. It is not a struct like Int32.

Comment: @Filip:  String is a class and is already allocated on the heap, .NET never allocates space off the stack to hold string data.

Comment: @Filip: What makes you think that `string` and `String` are different types?

Comment: Oh shit, Piere, you are right. I was referencering the wrong variable when I was doing the test.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: My ignorance and being awake at late night...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your premise is incorrect.  String is actually a reference type which just happens to act like a value type in many scenarios.  Type.IsValueType is the most reliable way of determining if a value would need to be boxed or not.

I'd be careful if you work with nullable values though.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just noticed I had a bug in my code where I referenced an int while I thought it was a string.

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing raw IL? That's the only case in which you'll have to concern yourself with boxing.

Comment: Yes, I am in fact writing raw IL, that's why I was asking.

Comment: Don't forget Hermann, that ints are i4 intrinsics and can often be operated on as intrinsics, without the boxing.